# How to get uploaded file using json API in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

Get uploaded file/ images using json-api

I want to fetch the uploaded files such as images using json api. Please provide me the steps/parameters to get the result.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation that comes with that plugin?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/